# Using TOUCH BEGIN/MOVE/END to create TAP / SWIPE events for four concurrent users

Tags: actionscript-3, air, multi-touch, user-interaction

I'm using a multi-touch screen for making an interactive presentation with Adobe AIR and four people is going to use the screen at once.

I've done some testing with MouseEvent (which works fine with one user) and I think that replacing that event with my own that can handle multiple users is the way to go, or did I miss something here?

Theres some work creating that event so i'd love some input, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my lousy explanation. I found your framework Gestouch which is exactly what I need! However there seems to be a problem with the SwipeGesture. I've been looking at the class and it seems to be connected to touch.time. If I use getTimer() instead of event[timestamp] in TouchInputAdapter it kinda works, otherwise touch.time is always the same. (I'm using AIR 3.2.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the inputMode to use multi-touch, then you'll want to be listening for TouchEvents instead of MouseEvents (believe for a single point at least it will still dispatch the MouseEvent, not sure if this is true for multiple touches though).

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSe11993ea1bd776e5-13e27e4812a431dbafc-8000.html

```
flash.ui.Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```